# Android asynctask not finishing its process

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I used an asynctask for uploading user data to server, But when i click on button the progressdialog still showing for long time, I used dialog.cancel in OnpostExecute() method of Asynctask, But its not working

Asynctask code:

```
private class Userdataupload2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
        // do above Server call here


        String s = "eroor";

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.webdev1.comxa.com/sciencequiz/user.php");


                int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
                SharedPreferences my2 = getSharedPreferences("fb", mode);
                String u = my2.getString("name", "error");
                String v = my2.getString("coin", "error");
                String ax = my2.getString("android_id", "error");
                String bx = my2.getString("device_model", "error");
                String cx = my2.getString("android_version", "error");
                String dx = my2.getString("cpu_info", "error");
                String ex = my2.getString("mem_info", "error");
                String fx = my2.getString("device_manufacturer", "error");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", u));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("coin", v));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("androidId", ax));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceModel", bx));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("androidVersion", cx));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cpuInfo", dx));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("memInfo", ex));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceManufacturer", fx));

                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //cancel(true);
                }

                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    // write response to log
                    //tdt(response.toString());
                    Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());

                    s = response.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // Log exception
                    //cancel(true);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Log exception
                    //cancel(true);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        return s;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message

        int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("data", mode);
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = data.edit();
        e.putInt("aa",1);
        e.commit();
        dialog.cancel();
        goToActivity(onlineranking.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute()
    {

    }
}
```

In Button click function:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    new Userdataupload2().get(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
            }).start();
```

I used new `Userdataupload2().get(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` because of stoping the task for 10s if there is no internet connectivity,

I tried many examples in stackoverflow, But all are in the case of downloading data, but I want to post/upload data
How to fix this issue?

EDIT:

I Want not only to cancel the progressdialog after some time, The progressdialog should dismissed or cancelled only after successful posting of data

Comment: What logs are telling you? Did you start your new thread?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't start your thread in Button click. `start()` is missing in your code.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                new Userdataupload2().get(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }
        }).start();
```

Comment: i tried your code, Now the time out 10s in get() method works, But nothing happends in server, No data was post to server,I think my code for posting data is correct

Comment: I also test my code by changing the time out from 10s to 60s, Now the progressdialog shows till 60s,and disappears, But for posting of about 2KB data less than 20s is enouph

Answer (score 0):

try `dialog.dismiss()` instead of `dialog.cancel()`

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message

        int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("data", mode);
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = data.edit();
        e.putInt("aa",1);
        e.commit();
        dialog.dismiss();
        goToActivity(onlineranking.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason is your handling this in a separate thread. I think there is no need of creating a new thread in button click. Just remove that new Thread(new Runnable...., 
and write your code with out creating a new thread. 
just like
          try {

new Userdataupload2().get(10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}

catch (InterruptedException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

catch (ExecutionException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

catch (TimeoutException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

dialog.cancel();

}

Comment: I created a new thread for calling asynctask for avoiding blocking of ui thread when using 'get()'